# Reading hex value from stringstream into uint8_t doesn't work, why?

Tags: c++, stringstream

The following code

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint8_t result = 0;
    std::stringstream ss("2B");
    ss << std::hex;
    ss >> result;

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs `2` with GCC 6.3 and `48` with clang on macOS. Why? The correct result is 43, and clearly it fits in `uint8_t` and even `int8_t`. However, replacing `uint8_t` with `uint16_t` results in `43`.

[Ideone link for this code](https://ideone.com/RggLk9)

Comment: As for the reason why it happens, most likely because the `char` overload is picked which extracts one `char` from the stream, then `cout` prints this `char`.

Comment: You need to analyse the code and the results more closely than that. Just getting the wrong result displayed doesn't (necessarily, and in this case) mean the read didn't work!

Comment: @SombreroChicken: that explains, thanks.